# Views module core patching inside a sub-site

Tags: views, 7, multi-sites

I have a multi-site setup like below:

abc-parent/sites/all/modules/views
abc-parent/sites/pqr-child/modules/views (consisting core patching done in views)

When i do the above i get errors like cannot redeclare function

I wanted to do a core patching for views inside just 'pqr-child' site so that customization remains only to pqr-child and not for all the sites inside 'abc-parent'

Can anyone please help me achieve the above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules that are placed inside `sites/all/modules` directory are accessible to all sites setup inside sites directory. Thats why it is showing you the error.

So basically you are trying to apply a patch for `pqr-child` site only. So you can do :

1. If it is a general patch, you can apply it to `sites/all/modules/views` directory. So there is no need of adding views directory for pqr-child site.
2. If it is a **hack**, then my suggestion is not to hack the module, instead you can write a custom module to fulfil your requirements.
3. But if it still necessary to hack the module, you need to copy the `sites/all/modules/views` to all the `sites/subsites/modules` directory and delete it from `sites/all/modules`.